# A problem to prove $f'(c)$ as a sum of the given elements as in problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, rolles-theorem

> Let $f\colon [a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $f''(x)$ exists for all $x\in (a,b)$. Let $a<c<b$, then there exists a point $\xi$  in $(a,b)$ such that
> $$ f(c)=\frac{b-c}{b-a}f(a)+\frac{c-a}{b-a}f(b)+\frac12(c-a)(c-b)f''(\xi).$$

In this problem, instantaneously I am thinking of applying  Rolle s ' theorem.. Am I correct in my thought approach?
If not kindly provide a way out how to solve this problem elegantly..thank you .
Even in Rolle s how can I go about.... The RHS seems so frightening to prove ......

Any ideas how to go about this problem ...anyone

Comment: To simplify the expression, first consider the case $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Our goal is then 
$$ f(c)=\frac 12(c-a)(c-b)f''(\xi).$$ Later, add some $Ax+B$ to $f$ and nobserve that it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen...can you explain me the Ax+B part a bit more.... I mean I don't get u.. I am sorry for that...A elaborate answer in the answer section.... Would be appreciable... Thank you

Comment: Any idea..... Anyone please help